# Blazor WASM Deploy to IIS Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I developed a Balzor WASM and it works on local machine with bellow structure :

[image]

But when I deploy to IIS it show me this error :

```
{"error":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

[image]

It is very strange that has no any http 500 error in debug mode but when I hosted on IIS it shows me this error.
There is no any additional information in page or event viewer!
Another thing is I host both release and debug files on IIS. I shows me this message again!
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Open up the Developer tool in the browser - F12 - and look at what errors you are seeing.

Comment: Error 500 on IIS, But there is no error on local machine @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: Error 500 is pretty generic, it could be almost anything.  Look up "Troubleshooting IIS 500 errors" on the net to find articles on how to narrow down the problem.  As it stands this question doesn't contain enough information for a sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be json and is strange that is on your index page of the WASM client.

The only possibility I can think is a request from your index.hrml to your backend but there's a problem of configuration.

Check your endpoint base address in your appsettings.json in your wwwroot of the client app.

Try to use postman (or another client like it) to test calls to your backend when hosted on IIS.